# how do I get the top 3 columns items based on a given column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given this sample table:

```
ID_no         name             grade
112           Micheal          81
113           Airi             90
114           Felix            76
115           Ana              87
```

how do i get the top 3 names based on their given grades...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use the `TOP` clause in combination with your desired order:

```
SELECT TOP 3 Name, SUM(Grade)AS Grade
FROM table
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Grade DESC
```

(assuming that a higher grade is better)

Note that you need `SELECT TOP 3 WITH TIES` (as John has shown) to include all rows with the same number. So consider that there are 5 names with the same grade, my query would only return 3 whereas `WITH TIES` ensures that all 5 are returned.

Comment: i have a question, what if you have these results, `90, 87, 80, 80, 79`, how will you handle ties at `80`?